# List View Web Part ignores mods to underlying view

Tags: 2010, list-view, custom-form

I have a list "Items". Using SPD, I have created a view "Featured Item", and edited the view and its properties so it displays a single item in a meaningful way. The view works great when viewing the list directly.

In the same web where the list is, on the intro page of the web, I add a List View Web Part to display the list. I manually switch the view to "Featured Item".

The strange thing is, the view is rendered, but not with any of the modifications I made to it. If I switch to viewing the list itself, the modified version of the view is displayed as desired. I switch back to the intro page, and the original version of the view is displayed.

The intro page has been checked in, etc. This seems to be some weird issue with the LVWP refusing to pick up any updates to the view. I'm at a loss on what to do next, and google has not been my friend on this one.

Fwiw, this is SP2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a list view web part and select a "featured" view that has been defined in the list itself, a copy of that view will be created and the web part on that page will point to the copy, not the original in the list. There is no connection between the two views. Any changes that you make in the list view will NOT be reflected in the web part's view.

This is just something to be aware of. It is by design.

The quickest way to get the web part to show the current list view is to delete the web part, create a new list view web part and select the "featured" view.

Comment: This is true and I'm accepting it as the answer.I did find a workaround, however. In SPD, if you edit the view and copy all the text between the opening and closing <Xsl> tags, and save that as a file with an .xsl extention, it can be refenced in the XSL Path field which is visible when editing the LVWP properties. Unfortunately, if one enables a data filter connection between the LVWP and another web part, the .xsl file gets ignored.

Comment: After another day, I can tell more. Actually, the XSL Path does indeed render the view according to the XSL. BUT... If you enable a data Connection bteween two web parts, the resulting "double arrow" picker icon added to the front of each row in your list is added in wrapped in a TD. So, if like me, your XSL is built with multiple rows, you will have to manually add in an empty first TD pair at the start of each row after the first one. I hope that wasn't too confusing.